# How to extract values from list?

Tags: r

I have a list which looks like the following:

```
list(Element1 =  c('ra12345', 'ra13467'),
     Element2 = c('ra3467', 'ra5643', 'ra55959'))
```

I want to run through each element in the list, remove the 'ra' to just leave the integers and then to be able to access each integer individually. I.e. for element 1, I want to be able to access 12345 and 13467 individually, however, I don't know how to do so.

I've tried:

```
for (I in length(listName)) {
 variable <- gsub("rs", "", listName[i])

}
```

But this returns:
`c(\"12345\", \"ra13467\")`

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question, that may be a `[` vs. `[[` thing. If that is the case, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(Element1 = c('ra12345','ra13467'), Element2 = c('ra3467', 'ra5643', 'ra55959'))

map(l, parse_number)

#> $Element1
#> [1] 12345 13467
#> 
#> $Element2
#> [1]  3467  5643 55959
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I get the following error: Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row col expected actual
 14  -- a number

Comment: Are you using my list `l`or other data?

Answer (score 1):

```
list(Element1 =  c('ra12345', 'ra13467'),
     Element2 = c('ra3467', 'ra5643', 'ra55959')) %>% 
  purrr::map(readr::parse_number())
```

Result:

```
$Element1
[1] 12345 13467

$Element2
[1]  3467  5643 55959
```

The only difference to Paul's solution in the end is that `extract_numeric()` returns numeric values, while `str_remove` returns a character value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It says extract numeric is outdated though?

Comment: Yes, this one should not be used. From the help file: "DEPRECATED: please use readr::parse_number() instead."

Comment: @Adam I then get: Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @github292929 I would guess then that either (a) your packages may need updating or (b) your real problem has features outside of your reproducible example. Because it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option in base R.

```r
l <- list(Element1 = c('ra12345','ra13467'),
          Element2 = c('ra3467', 'ra5643', 'ra55959'))

l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("ra", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))
l2
# $Element1
# [1] 12345 13467
# 
# $Element2
# [1]  3467  5643 55959

str(l2)
# List of 2
#  $ Element1: num [1:2] 12345 13467
#  $ Element2: num [1:3] 3467 5643 55959
```